# copy the snippet java file in middle of temp file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a beginner in python3
I want to copy snippet java file in the middle of other temp file which i gain the address of this file from downloading URL.
my problem is when i execute my program i have this error:

---

```
RESTART: C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/refactordwon.py 
the Url is: 
('C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpq5m7m_og', <http.client.HTTPMessage object at 0x0000003A854879E8>)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/refactordwon.py", line 14, in <module>
    file_out = open("path_file" , "r")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'path_file'
>>>
```

---

i do not know why?
because when i download the url, url shows me this address:

```
  the Url is: 
    ('C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpey3yovte', <http.client.HTTPMessage object at 0x0000002233347978>)
```

---

i tried to use this address in different way but anyway i have error. i found the temp file and copied in python address.
I am sure that i have this file and the address is correct but again i have error that can not find file.
could you help me, please?!

I hope my question is clear

my code is:

```
   import urllib.request
import os
import tempfile
#download URL
#[-------------------------
url = 'http://pages.di.unipi.it/corradini/Didattica/AP-17/PROG-ASS/03/assignment3.html'
gt_url = urllib.request.urlretrieve(url)
print("the Url is: ")
print(gt_url)
#--------------------------]
#copy sniper java file inside remote file
#[--------------------------
path_file =r'C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/tmpokv2s_dw'
file_out = open("path_file" , "r")
file_in = open("snip1.java", "r")
file_out.readlines()
open("file_back", "w")
file_back.write(file_out)
pos_fileout = file_back.tell()
file_back.seek(pos_fileout)
file_back.write(file_in)
print("the content of file is: ")
file_back.close()
file_out.close()
file_in.close()
open("file_back", "r")
file_back.readlines()
print(file_back)
file_back.close()
```

Comment: Please stick to one version-specific tag in a question.

Comment: The traceback tells you exactly what's wrong: it's looking for a file called "path_file", and not finding it. What you probably meant was `open(path_file , "r")` (without the quotes around `path_file`).

Comment: i forget put quotes for path_file

Comment: anyway i did but again i have this error. but i am sure that this path is true and i have this file

Comment: Let me rephrase: by putting quotes around `path_file` in the `open()` statement, you're saying "Open a file called path_file". What you actually want to say is "Open a file whose name is in the `path_file` variable", which you do with `open(path_file, "r")` (remove the quotes around `path_file`).

Comment: thank you yes is correct. i removed the quotes around the path_file.but my errors continue.I think my problem is about my code.I want copy the content of snip java file in middle of path_file which is temp file.I think i did something wrong